# How to validate date input of format DD-MMM-YYYY?

Tags: java, validation, date

I have to check if date is in format DD-MMM-YYYY.e.g

01-JAN-2010  // true
01/01/2010 // false
.
.
Anything else //false

Comment: What have you attempted and what is the problem?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14886-date-validation-using-simpledateformat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String dt = "01-JAN-2013";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

try {
     df.parse(dt);
     System.out.println("true");
} catch (ParseException e) {
     System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: it will not work check with this date string 111-Jan-2021

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
    boolean flag = true;
    String dateInString  = "01-JAN-2010";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy");
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        flag = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        System.out.println(flag?"Success":"Failure");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private List<DateFormat> acceptedFormats = Arrays.asList(
     new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");


public boolean validate(String date) {
    for ( DateFormat fmt : acceptedFormats ) {
        try {
            fmt.parse(date);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Nice that you put the list of accepted format. It will be easy to extend.